# How can I turn a string containing a dollar amount into an integer?

Tags: ruby, gsub

How can I turn a string containing a dollar value in the form `"$39,900"` into an integer so I can perform calculations with it?

I figured I would try `gsub`, but that doesn't appear to work:

```
str = "$39,900"
str.strip.gsub('$' '')
=> #<Enumerator: "$39,900":gsub("$")>
```

Can someone please share with me the proper way to go about this?

Comment: Please, always try to ask a *specific* question and provide the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce your problem and find a solution. The fact that your string came from a website has **nothing** to do with the question you're asking, and including the entire output of the scraped page cannot possibly be of any use.

Comment: This isn't a Nokogiri problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
str = "$39,900"
str.tr('^0-9', '').to_i # => 39900
```

Here's how it breaks down:

```
str # => "$39,900"
.tr('^0-9', '') # => "39900"
.to_i # => 39900
```

`'^0-9', ''` in `tr` means "replace everything that is not 0..9 with `''`, resulting in only digits.

[`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-tr) is extremely fast, much faster than `gsub` for this use, and well worth knowing about and using for this sort of problem.

If you *insist* on using `gsub` with a regex, this will do it:

```
str.gsub(/\D+/, '').to_i # => 39900
```

however I'd still recommend using `tr`. Here's why:

```
require 'fruity'

str = "$39,900"
compare do
  _gsub { str.gsub(/\D+/, '') }
  _tr { str.tr('^0-9', '') }
  jason_yost { str.scan(/\d/).join('') }
  nikita_mishain { str.tr('$,', '') }
  ruben_tf { str.gsub(/[^\d]/, '') }
end

# >> Running each test 8192 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> nikita_mishain is similar to _tr
# >> _tr is faster than ruben_tf by 4x ± 1.0
# >> ruben_tf is similar to _gsub
# >> _gsub is faster than jason_yost by 2x ± 0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

`.gsub('$' '')` --> `.gsub('$', '')`  (missing a comma)

Comment: how do I do a multiple gsub of substituting the '$' and ',' at the same time?

Comment: You can chain the two gsub clauses, or you could use regex.

Answer (score 1):

`str.tr('$,', '').to_i` should work

I used `#tr` here. How it works is best explained in [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr)

Answer (score 1):

A regexp version would be:

```
str.gsub(/[^\d]/, '').to_i
```

Where `[^\d]` stands for "every character that's not a number".

Comment: You could also do `/\D/` to match non digits. Probably ought to worry about cents though :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "$39,900"
str.scan(/\d/).join('').to_i
=> 39900
```

If the string doesn't contain a number this will return `0`

```
str = "test"
str.scan(/\d/).join('').to_i
=> 0
```

This will not handle decimal properly. If you need to get a float value you can use

```
str = '%.2f' % '$39,000.99'.delete( "$" ).delete(',')
str.to_f
=> 39000.99
```